# How do I get Vordt's Hammer?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I got the soul of Vordt after killing him, but I read in the wiki that his hammer can be made using it. 
But when I try to use it I get 2000 souls but no hammer. 
I am new to the souls games. How do I get the hammer?

Comment: Like the answers said you've lost your chance at this weapon into NG+. Honestly, if you really want to use that weapon, I'd just restart on a new character. You can probably get back and defeat that boss fairly quickly now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that you have consumed the soul of Vordt, you cannot get the hammer (until NG+).

To transform a boss soul into a weapon/spell/ring, you have to get the Transposing Kiln from the Curse-Rotted Greatwood (Undead Settlement boss) and give it to Ludleth of Courland (the guy who sits on the throne in Firelink). Once given, you can trade your boss souls with him.

Source : http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Soul+Transposition

Comment: he can still get the hammer in ng+

Answer (score 12):

Soul Transposition in Dark Souls 3 is the process of converting a Boss Soul into a Weapon, or Ring. In order to create items you must have the specific Boss Soul, **you must have the Transposing Kiln which drops from Curse-Rotted Greatwood, and you must speak with Ludleth of Courland in Firelink Shrine.**

Ludlet will convert the souls to items.

[Source.](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Soul+Transposition)

PS: For as far as I know, when a boss soul is consumed to gain souls, you lose the soul, and will be unable to forge it to items. Untill you beat the boss again in NG+ (or new game with an other character ofcourse.)

Comment: You are correct, the boss soul is consumed when you activate it to get souls. Also, the boss soul can usually be transposed into 2 different items, but you can only pick one, so choose wisely.